# Java Prime Number check with User Input

Tags: java, input, numbers, controls

I just started coding for college and I had to write a program that checks user inputs (integers) if they're a prime number or not.

I've been getting good results but I wanted to ask for your opinion and whether I forgot something.

```
package uebung_3;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimZahlen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        int in = key.nextInt();

        prim(in);
    }

    private static void prim(int in) {//int in is a Scanner var.
        if (in == 2 || in == 3) {

            System.out.println(in + " is a prime number");
        } else if (in == 5 || in == 7) {
            System.out.println(in + " is a prime number");
        } else if (in % 2 == 0 || in % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(in + " is not a prime number.");
        } else if (in % 5 == 0 || in % 7 == 0) {
            System.out.println(in + " is not a prime number.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(in + " is a prime number.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot all the prime factors bigger than 7, e.g. this will say that 121 is a prime number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in a more mathematical way and not only check until prime factor 7.
Here is my solution:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    final Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int in = key.nextInt();

    if (isPrime(in)) {
        System.out.println(in + " is a prime number");
    } else {
        System.out.println(in + " is not a prime number");
    }
}

private static boolean isPrime(final int in) {
    if (in < 2) return false;

    for (int i=2; i <= Math.sqrt(in); i++){
        if (in%i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shold check that number has only 2 devisors (1 and himself).

For example:

```
static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Range for iteration can be optimized (from 2 to i^2<=n)

Comment: Why sqrt(n), but not n / 2?

Comment: @Russiancold because you only need to check up to `sqrt(n)`. For example, if you're checking 49, the only possible prime factors are 2, 3, 5 or 7. It cannot be divisible by 11 because 49/11 is less than 7, so you'd already have found a factor.

Comment: If number hasn't divisor less then `sqrt(n)` it can't has divisor more than `sqrt(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Prime numbers have only 2 divisors the 1 and the number itself. So to check whether a number is prime or not you have to check all the possible divisors of that number.
For example:

```
boolean isPrimeNumber(int num){
    if(num < 2)
        return false;
    for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So 1 is prime, is it?

Comment: According to the Prime number definition 
“An integer greater than one is called a prime number if its only positive divisors (factors) are one and itself”

So 1 is not a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia entry on [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode) gives a better algorithm for testing than presented so far and we can implement it in Java trivially enough like

```
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    } else if (n <= 3) {
        return true;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int sq = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
    for (int i = 5; i <= sq; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % 2 + i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And change your `main` method to use it, something like

```
// prim(in);
if (isPrime(in)) {
    System.out.printf("%d is prime.%n", in);
} else {
    System.out.printf("%d is not prime.%n", in);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer @ElliotFrish, but I'd say the last **if** should be `if (n % i == 0 || n % (2 + i) == 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your program is incorrect. This is right implementation which now check all integer numbers from minus infinity to infinity considering 1 as non-prime number:

```
public boolean isPrime(int number) {
        if(number < 2) return false;
        for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
            if(n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: So how should I say it?

Comment: I'm sorry. Language barrier. It hadn't got any negative context

Comment: I also wouldn't say "suddenly". There's nothing sudden here.

Comment: Unexpectedly turned into some "Good manners tips for english learners")) Thanks for correction.

Comment: "This is right implementation" It's not, though. 0 isn't a prime number, negative numbers aren't prime either. You can fix it using `if (number <= 2) return number == 2;`. Also, note that you can then change the loop to start at 3 and increment by 2.

Comment: @AndyTurner your method worked perfectly! Its just a simple exercise nothing that needs to be super accurate.

Comment: @Steve the real value of this answer is below)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you're not checking prime factors greater than 7; this means that you'll start getting the wrong answer for `n >= 121`.

Just because everybody else has basically proposed the same algorithm, here's another one which is simple to implement: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) return false;

  // sieve is basically a boolean[], where each element will
  // contain "true" if the number is prime, "false" otherwise.
  BitSet sieve = new BitSet(n + 1);
  sieve.set(0, n + 1);

  // Zero isn't prime, nor is 1.
  sieve.clear(0); sieve.clear(1);

  for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (sieve.get(i)) {
      // i is a prime number.
      // Mark all multiples of i as non-prime.
      for (int j = 2 * i; j <= n; j += i) {
        sieve.clear(j);
      }
    }
  }

  // n is prime if the corresponding element in the sieve is "true".
  return sieve.get(n);
}
```

Note that you can factor this in such a way that you can reuse the `sieve` `BitSet` for multiple calls to the method (specifically, you can use it again for a smaller value of `n`).

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I will try this method, but I dont really understand every part just yet (bit set).

Comment: @Steve a `BitSet` is just a memory-efficient alternative to a `boolean[]`.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm always glad to learn something new :D